# To resolve Warning of node_module in react native project after npm install react-native-modalbox

Tags: firebase, react-native, expo

Now I am making an app in react native.
A Few days ago, I needed to use Modal in my app so I have installed "react-native-modalbox".(https://github.com/maxs15/react-native-modalbox)

But after that, I got Warning like the image below.

[image]

I couldn't get this mean and a way to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

I see this warning as simply a warning that does not affect the code.

This would be simply a Metro warning.

But if you want to get rid of this,

```js
import { YellowBox } from "react-native";
YellowBox.ignoreWarnings(["Require cycle:", "Remote debugger"]);
```

I hope you to refer to [this.](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/debugging)

OR

I Referenced this [link](https://github.com/facebook/metro/issues/287#issuecomment-444177106)

Add a `scripts` folder in your project

Create a `stfu.js` file with the following content

```js
const fs = require('fs');

const codeToObscure = /console.warn\([\s\S].*"Require cycle: "/;
const problemFilePath = './node_modules/metro/src/lib/polyfills/require.js';
const problemFileContent = fs.readFileSync(problemFilePath,'utf8');
fs.writeFileSync(problemFilePath,problemFileContent.replace(codeToObscure,'const noConsoleWarn = (""'),'utf8');
```

Add the following line to your `package.json` in your `scripts` : `"postinstall": "node ./scripts/stfu.js"`,
When it's done, just `rm -rf node_modules && yarn` to reinstall everything, and make sure these damn warnings are now gone.

I hope these methods work for you.

Comment: What did you mean with "stfu.js" filename?